# How to retrieve, save and renew idToken from google Passport

Tags: node.js, passport.js, passport-google-oauth

I am using google oauth passport strategy in my nodejs app and I don't know the right way to store and renew my idToken, so I can use it for authentication purposes when making api calls to an external api. Presently, I'm writing the token to a textfile and reading it from there. I feel this is a bad idea and just need suggestions on how to do it in a more elegant way.

```
module.exports = function (passport) {


passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
    clientID: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
    clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
    
    callbackURL: url    },
async (accessToken, refreshToken, params, profile, done) => {
       const idToken = params.id_token
       
       fs.writeFile('token.txt', idToken, err => {
        if (err) {
          console.error(err)
          return
        }
        //file written successfully
        console.log("file written successfully")
      })         
      }
```

Comment: id_token is needed to auto-generate access_token after 3600ms, without interactive login (no human user). #1 Is this your requirement ? This is not a common requirement. Common requirement is to have a web with "google sing-in" button, exchange the auth_code to obtain access_token and use access_token to consume any google platform api. #2 will you invoke just google apis or are you developing your own rest apis? #3 Are you developing a web application with client side rendering or server side rendering technique?

Comment: @JRichardsz Yes I have a google sign-in button but in this case, I need the id_token from google to authenticate on an external api so I can obtain bearer tokens which will give me authorization to perform certain actions on the external api. The web application is using server-side rendering.

Comment: The external api is not a google api. This will explain what I am trying to implement but with passport-google-oauth: https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/backend-auth#verify-the-integrity-of-the-id-token

Comment: @JRichardsz If my api is my own endpoints and not Google's, I would generate my own access_token instead of using the one provided by Google, is that correct?

Comment: @chris, you are right. But in that case you will need to use or develop another platform to manage your authentication and authorization. Platforms like that are called IAM or oruaht2 openid service provider. Some of them are: auth0, okta, keycloack, hydra, etc

Comment: @JRichardsz thanks for responding! I'm still a little confused. So after I get the id_token from Google, can't my server just generate its own access and refresh tokens and send those to the client so that subsequent calls to my API by that user are authorized? Why would I need auth0 or okta in those scenarios? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As another poster indicated, if you are using the token purely for login, you may not need to store and renew the ID token at all.

However, if you are using the token to access Google APIs, and you need access even without the user present, the most common approach is:

- Store the access token and refresh token encrypted in a database, both associated with the user
- When using the access token, check for an error response from Google that indicates that the token has expired, use the refresh token to get a new access token, and save that new access token in your database (again, encrypted)

In Google's case, be sure to pass the `access_type=offline` parameter to retrieve an refresh token. Also, if this is a user you have previously authorized, you'll need to pass `prompt=consent`, as otherwise Google will not issue a refresh token.

An alternative to implementing all of the above is to use a managed OAuth service like [Xkit](https://xkit.co), where I work. It handles storing, encrypting, and refreshing tokens, and all of the provider-specific nuances. Again, only useful in cases where you're using the tokens to access APIs (and not for login), but another option to consider.

Comment: I tried to implement your suggestion but only works for a while and stops working. I have to delete the user from the database before its starts working again. Here it is: https://gist.github.com/dayoadisa/31507f0ba8812abf76e960f3b8d12dfb

Comment: https://gist.github.com/dayoadisa/31507f0ba8812abf76e960f3b8d12dfb#file-tokenvalidator-js-L33 that parameter looks wrong. Check the camel case vs snake case on both parameters.

Comment: req.user.refreshToken is what I have in the database. The issue I am facing is it renews the tokens after the first expiration but on trying it the second time when the token has expired it won't work. Why does it work the first time and not afterwards